# How to get all documents in one reading Firebase

Tags: spring, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I am expanding a project originally made for mobiles, making a web management system with spring, for which the data is loaded by the mobiles to a Firestore db.
My problem is that when I list all the documents in a collection, google counts the number of reads by the number of documents in that collection.

```
public List<MemberDTO> list() {
        List<MemberDTO> response = new ArrayList<>();
        MemberDTO post;
        ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshotApiFuture = getCollection().get();
        try {
            for (DocumentSnapshot doc : querySnapshotApiFuture.get().getDocuments()) {
                post = doc.toObject(MemberDTO.class);
                response.add(post);
            }
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
private CollectionReference getCollection() {
        return firebase.getFirestore().collection("MEMBERS");
    }
```

Therefore, having approximately 1000 documents in the production db, in one hour of use I reach the limit of 50,000 readings.

Getting all documents in a collection using a single firebase read, I got n number of reads where n is the number of documents.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected and documented behavior. This part of the pricing model is based on **document** reads, so you're charged per document that you read. If you want to be charged fewer document reads, the solution is to read fewer documents, for example by [implementing pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

If you're new to Firestore, I recommend checking out the excellent video series [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). For this topic, there is an entire episode on [Firestore pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=3).

Comment: Thank you! It has been a great help to me